# Parse a string array in json response

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have to accept the json response in below format which can have many "fields" in the string array. What would be the simplest way to parse this in a loop where I can extract "fieldvalues" and do some operations on them?

```
 {
   "fields":
 [
   "/field1/{field1value}/field2/{field2value}/field3/{field3value}",
   "/field1/{field1value}/field2/{field2value}/field3/{field3value}"
 ]
 }
```

Comment: What is your problem? Reading the json as an array with two strings or processing the content of these two strings? As usual a piece of code with your attempt to solve the problem is the best way to explain the problem

Comment: If you mean "parsing JSON": Don't do it, Json.NET does this for you! If you mean "parse a string in an array" then this question is not related to JSON at all.

Comment: @Steve I'll try to ask this better, it's both. My usual approach is receive the response as JObject and then do $"{json["fields"]}" to get the string, but in this case that'll give me a huge string. I looked up JArray.Parse, but couldn't make that work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to parse the JSON and iterate over the strings in the `fields` array, you can do that like this:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var path in obj["fields"].Values<string>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

If you need to break down the strings into name-value pairs, you can split on `/` and loop over the parts like this (inside the previous loop):

```
    string[] parts = path.Split('/');
    for (var i = 1; i < parts.Length; i += 2)
    {
        var name = parts[i];
        var value = (i + 1 < parts.Length) ? parts[i + 1] : null;

        Console.WriteLine(name + ": " + value);
    }
```

See fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TupvAu

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful, I was looking for something like Values function.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse that Json and obtain the single lines of data in this way

```
// As an example for your input data.....
string json =  "{\"fields\":[\"/field1/{field1value}/field2/{field2value}/field3/{field3value}\",\"/field1/{field1value}/field2/{field2value}/field3/{field3value}\"]}";

// Json.NET JObject.Parse
var lines = JObject.Parse(json);
// Remove comment with LinqPad 
// lines.GetType().Dump();
// Not really needed to explicitly use the Properties method...
foreach (var x in lines.Properties())
{
    // Remove comment with LinqPad 
    // x.GetType().Dump();
    foreach (var k in x.Value)
    {
        // Remove comment with LinqPad 
        // k.GetType().Dump();
        string dataLine = k.Value<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(dataLine);
    }
}
```

I suggest to try this code with LinqPad using the Dump method on the variables lines, x and k to understand the inner structure of that JObject returned by Parse.